# Angular 6 Basic Auth returns 401 from client

Tags: java, angular, angular6, basic-authentication

So I've looked around for the answer to my problem for quite a while now and tried many suggestions but I can't seem to find an answer.

The problem is, when I use Postman to check if basic auth works I get a 200 code back and it's all good, but as soon as I try to authenticate using my Login Component I get the code 401 back and says "Full authentication is required to access this resource".

I'm fairly new to Angular and completely new to using Basic Auth so I have no idea why does it work with Postman and why doesn't it work from the app.

Any help is appreciated

Below are the relevant codes

log-in.component.ts:

```
onLogin(form: NgForm) {
    /* ... */
    let headers = new Headers();
    let userCredentials = user.userName + ":" + user.password;
    headers.append("Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(userCredentials));

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/users/login', headers).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        /* ... */
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
}
```

Endpoint on the server side:

```
@PostMapping(LOG_IN)
public ResponseEntity<User> login() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint())
                .and()
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password("1234").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    protected void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint getBasicAuthEntryPoint(){
        return new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint:

```
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, 
            final HttpServletResponse response, 
            final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + getRealmName() + "");

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("HTTP Status 401 : " + authException.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setRealmName("MY REALM");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

MyUserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> oUser = userRepository.findByUserName(username);

        if (!oUser.isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }

        User user = oUser.get();
        authenticatedUser.setUser(user);
        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().toString()));

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

Comment: What  the type of your http instance? Http or HtppClient?

Comment: It's Http. Could it cause the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the headers as 3rd parameter for the post method. The 2nd one is the body

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/users/login', {}, {headers}).subscribe(
  (response) => {
```

If you are using angular 6, you should really be using the new `HttpClient` class, the old `Http` class being deprecated

Comment: Oh my god thank you! I can't believe I've spent hours of debugging and googling only to realize it was a typo like this all along! Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 0):

This is because the browser send OPTION method to the server  before send your request,  , try to update your security configuration by  allowing OPTION method. like this

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
     http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/path/to/allow").permitAll()//allow CORS option calls
      .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that once before. I've tried it again but it doesn't help at all. In chrome devtools in network tab I see 2 login requests, one is OPTIONS and that returns with a 200 but the one after is POST and that returns with 401. I assume the OPTIONS one is the preflight?